# Android rotation matrix not rotating around a point

Tags: java, android, matrix

I have been researching how to rotate Bitmaps in android, the only one I could find was using a Matrix. This works for rotations under 90 degrees, but it seems every 90 degrees the rotation point wobbles. Heres my code, if you want me to post an image/gif [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE4ZA.jpg) of the result please say so. Thank you for your help

```
    Matrix leftMat = new Matrix();
    leftMat.setRotate ((float) (debug),thrustWidth,0);
    Bitmap leftThruster = Bitmap.createBitmap (thruster,0,0, thruster.getWidth(),thruster.getHeight (),leftMat,true);
    leftThruster.setHasAlpha(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(leftThruster,(int) (shipX +leftCords[0]),(int) (shipY+leftCords[1]-cameraY),null);
```

EDIT: It seems that the corners of the image try to meet up with the corners of the "bounding box" but I can't seem to get more than that.

EDIT: Updated code (Not exact copy, but hopefully it gives everything that's important, I also replaced all the variables with constants where applicable for clarity)

```
    private Bitmap thruster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.thruster);
    private float debug = 0;
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        debug ++;
        Matrix leftMat = new Matrix();  
        leftMat.postRotate(debug,0,0);
        Bitmap leftThruster = Bitmap.createBitmap (thruster,0,0, thruster.getWidth(),thruster.getHeight(),leftMat,false);
        leftThruster.setHasAlpha(false);
        canvas.drawBitmap(leftThruster, 300, 300,null);
```

Comment: It looks like you have at least 2 problems; your pivot point isn't always in the same place, and in at least some cases it appears to actually lie outside the bounding box of your bitmap.  Please provide more complete code that shows how variables like `thrustWidth`, `leftCords` and `cameraY` are populated.

Comment: Will do, though it doesn't seem to work even when I set the pivot points as 0,0

Comment: after setting the background to black instead of transparent, the problem seems more apparent. It looks like its rotating, but it translates so that it fits inside that box. It's a little hard to explain, I might put another visual.

Comment: Oh, I can pretty much visualize what's happening; your response confirms that.  I asked for complete code so that I could point to where you're not using the correct offsets to rotate and composite your bitmap.  A [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I updated the code so hopefully you should understand what all the variables are. If you need anything else please feel free to ask. Although, I do believe that if I translate ```leftThruster```  right it should provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I found a solution, though I don't know why that code doesn't work, I've found an alternate. Instead of `canvas.drawBitmap(leftThruster, 300, 300,null);` I replaced it with  `canvas.drawBitmap(thruster,leftMat,null);` While also adding `leftMat.postTranslate(300,300);` to leftMat.

Comment: a bit off topic but you should not rotate the bitmap but the canvas you are drawing on. Beside that you are calling `createBitmap()` inside your `draw()` method which is literally evil. Reason: This method gets called up to 60 times per second (or even more) so you create hundreds of bitmaps during a few seconds. This will eat battery and memory in no time. Load the bitmap once, call `canvas.save()`, rotate/translate the canvas with `canvas.setRotation()`/`canvas.setTranlation()` (probably, just from memory), draw the bitmap on the center and call `canvas.restore()` which "reverts" the canvas

Comment: Although with my new solution, I only load the Bitmap ‘’’thruster’’’ once as far as I know, and have gotten rid of the ‘’’leftThruster’’’ bitmap and now only a matrix is changed each frame.

Comment: So if the matrix is only changed and not created new: fine. The general rule is: don't create objects inside the draw methods

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this sample app that demo rotate image with matrix. that I previously implemented.

https://github.com/UdayaLakmal/GlideImageRotate

```
public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

that will return rotated bitmap with angle it pass.